# How to pass html element as child in Angular Higher Order Components (HOC)?

Tags: javascript, angular, higher-order-components, recompose, ng-component-outlet

I want to pass an HTML element in my Angular Higher Order Component. Right now I'm passing child element as a @Input decorator.
My HOC, Main Container is like this.

```
<div>
 <p> MY EXTRA UI HERE</p>
 <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="child"></ng-container>
</div>

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-container',
  templateUrl: './main-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-container.component.scss'],
})
export class MainContainerComponent {
  @Input() child
}
```

In other components I'm using my HOC like this

**My Current code:**

```
<app-main-container [child]="child"></app-main-container>
```

in .ts file I'm passing my child component like this

```
import { SidebarComponent } from '../sidebar/sidebar.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-staff',
  templateUrl: './staff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./staff.component.scss'],
})
export class StaffComponent {
  child: any = SidebarComponent
}
```

Now what I want to do is, something like this in React format

```
<app-main-container> 
    <app-staff-sidebar></app-staff-sidebar>
</app-main-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure you defined in your question

```
<app-main-container> 
    <app-staff-sidebar></app-staff-sidebar>
</app-main-container>
```

we can achieve this using `ng-content`.

Your `main-container.component.html` should accept it like so:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- This will be exchanged with the `<app-staff-sidebar></app-staff-sidebar>` that you passed in.
</div>
```

Assuming you want to insert more content that should be rendered a little differently than just by plain yielding, you can use `slots` represented by the `select` keyword. It is basically trying to find the provided pattern.

Calling the structure like so:

```
<app-main-container>
  <app-staff-sidebar data-slot-type="right"></app-staff-sidebar>
  <div data-slot-type="left"></div>
</app-main-container>
```

And accepting the slots like this:

```
<div class="main-container">
  <ng-content select="[data-slot-type=left]"></ng-content>
  <ng-content select="[data-slot-type=right]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

The `select` can match any given pattern. It can be a CSS class, an entire tag or anything else the DOM represents.

Comment: Thank you so much Philipp Meissner, your solution is working perfectly 

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! Feel free to accept the answers if it fully answers your question :)